# PHP: php_serial.class.php Send String/Hex

Tags: php, string, serial-port, hex

I use the php_serial.class.php and have one question. When I send this below line to my device everything runs fine.

```
$serial->sendMessage("\x02\x06\xf1");
```

But when I do this way, nothing happens.

```
$str = "\x02\x06\xf1";
$serial->sendMessage($str);
```

Anybody has any idea as why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. Converting the string to binary with pack is the solution.

```
$str = "\x02\x06\xf1";
$str = pack("H*",$str);
$serial->sendMessage($str);
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
var $str = "\x02\x06\xf1";
$serial->sendMessage($str);
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks. But nothing changes.